# Can anybody identify this clay?

Tags: clay

One of my friends found a bunch of clay in their basement, still sealed, but outside of the original package. However, I am unable to figure out what kind of clay it is. I've checked the EberhardFaber site, but they no longer seem to sell this specific type, or I simply can't recognize it because it's outside of the original package.

Things I've tried:

- Airdry it, it's sat for a day without looking like it'll harden in
  the slightest.
- Bake it for a few minutes on a high temperature, the clay goes runny and melty.
- Bake it for 15 minutes on a lower temperature, the clay also goes slightly goopy. Does not harden after cooling down again.

[image: Image of the clay]

Comment: Have you noticed the number 8401 on the label?

Comment: I have, but "Eberhard Faber 8401" gets me no useful results on google. I think the product might have been discontinued or something, or the number is not an actual serial number but a production line stamp.

Comment: I googled in Dutch (one of the languages on the label) and found you this link. If you think it is right, I will convert it into an answer. https://artsupplyshop.nl/products/boetseerpasta/767825.html

Comment: It's possible, although my package contains 460G. That one claims it's airdry, which mine seems like it doesn't wan to do, though.

Comment: In that case I am not converting it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is non-hardening plasteline, also known as [plastecine](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plasticine).

For the record, although it is labeled as children’s modeling clay, I do not trust it to be non-toxic. Having worked with exactly this product in the past, I did find it to be great when building seals in damming walls of casting molds. If you want it to be harder, you can cool it / freeze it. This will not harden it, as you are only performing a state change in the oils / paraffins that are used to keep the mass malleable. I would be very cautious of overheating it, as you are likely to generate toxic fumes.

Comment: Thank you, this explains a lot. I tried just about every trick I could come up with to get it to cure.

Comment: @Theik - I updated my answer with a bit more information on the product.